# Failing build in TFS - log file not proving informative

Tags: logging, tfs, tfs-2015

I am troubleshooting a failing TFS 2015 build that I have inherited, which has the following error:

[image: TFS issues]

This error is almost certainly a character encoding issue in a batch file (as `ï»¿` is how a [UTF-8 BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) can be interpreted.

Source control contains a number of batch files which I and converted to UTF-8 (without BOM) using Notepad++.

[image: Notepad++]

This has not resolved the issue.

I hoped that TFS would contain logs that would tell me which file caused this issue, but the only log file I could find (*ActivityLog.xml*) this doesn't contain any information about this error.

Is there anywhere in TFS that contains additional logging information about build issues?

Comment: Where are you seeing that error? Can you provide a bit more context? Can you see it if you click "View Log" at the top of the build when you open it in Visual Studio?

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Can you get more error message if you build the solution locally?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using TFS 2012 XAML build, you can change the logging verbosity to `Diagnostic` in Build Definition directly to get more build log.

If you are using TFS 2013 XAML build, you can pass the parameter:
`/flp:verbosity="Diagnostic"` in the MSBuild arguments section, of the Process tab, in the build definition.

Additional, you can check event log in Event Viewer on your build agent machine to see whether there is more information there.